# ObjectDB Select query with too few parameters

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa, objectdb

I'm trying to populate a tsp page based on what parameter was passed to it.  Currently I'm using the title of the blog post, I don't like this but I wanted proof of concept and had difficulties obtaining the object id.  So, I'm temporarily passing in the title string with a view to change it later.

My query is throwing a too few arguments exception, none of the examples I've come across have lead me to believe that there is something missing so I'm slightly confused.  The call is:

```
    @Transactional
public objectName getObjectByTitle(String title){
    TypedQuery< objectName > query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT b FROM tableName AS b WHERE b.title = :title",
            objectName.class);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

with the error being:

```
com.objectdb.o._PersistenceException: Attempt to execute a query with too few arguments
```

It might be one of those cases where I'm looking too hard but I've scoured the objected site and cannot find a solution.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a named parameter in the query, and didn't bother setting its value (using setParameter), even though you went to the trouble of passing "title" in to the method ...